# React change url but not component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I click a link the URL changes but the component remains.

here is Router.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import ProductsList from "./ProductsList";
import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

class Router extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                    <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductsList}/>
                    <Route path="/productdetails" component={ProductDetails}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Router;
```

here is the productslist.js file where I click the link:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Table, Input, Button, Icon, Divider} from 'antd';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';
import {getProducts} from "../actions/productsActions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

class ProductsList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        searchText: '',
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getProducts();
    }

    getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
        filterDropdown: ({
                             setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters,
                         }) => (
            <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
                <Input
                    ref={node => { this.searchInput = node; }}
                    placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
                    value={selectedKeys[0]}
                    onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
                    onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
                    style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
                />
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm)}
                    icon="search"
                    size="small"
                    style={{ width: 90, marginRight: 8 }}
                >
                    Search
                </Button>
                <Button
                    onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
                    size="small"
                    style={{ width: 90 }}
                >
                    Reset
                </Button>
            </div>
        ),
        filterIcon: filtered => <Icon type="search" style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
        onFilter: (value, record) => record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
        onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
            if (visible) {
                setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
            }
        },
        render: (text) => (
            <Highlighter
                highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
                searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
                autoEscape
                textToHighlight={text.toString()}
            />
        ),
    })

    handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm) => {
        confirm();
        this.setState({ searchText: selectedKeys[0] });
    }

    handleReset = (clearFilters) => {
        clearFilters();
        this.setState({ searchText: '' });
    }

    render() {
        const data = this.props.productsList.map(product => {
                return {
                    key: product.id,
                    product_name: product.product_name,
                    id: product.id,
                    product_price: product.product_price,
                    product_gender: product.product_gender,
                    product_category: product.product_category,
                    product_campaign: product.product_campaign,
                    product_description: product.product_description


                }
            });
        const columns = [{
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'product_name',
            key: 'product_name',
            width: '20%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('product_name')
        }, {
            title: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            key: 'id',
            width: '10%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('id')
        }, {
            title: 'Price',
            dataIndex: 'product_price',
            key: 'product_price',
            width: '10%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('product_price'),
        }, {
            title: 'Gender',
            dataIndex: 'product_gender',
            key: 'product_gender',
            width: '10%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('product_gender'),
        }, {
            title: 'Category',
            dataIndex: 'product_category',
            key: 'product_category',
            width: '10%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('product_category'),
        }, {
            title: 'Campaign',
            dataIndex: 'product_campaign',
            key: 'product_campaign',
            width: '10%',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('product_campaign'),
        }, {
            title: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'product_description',
            key: 'product_description',
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('product_description'),
        }, {
            title: 'Action',
            key: 'action',
            render: (text, record) => (
                <span>
                <Link to={`/productdetails`}>Edit</Link>
                <Divider type="vertical" />
                <a href="javascript:">Delete</a>
                </span>
            ),
        }];
        return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={{ pageSize: 16 }} />;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        productsList: state.productsReducer.products
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getProducts})(ProductsList);
```

So in productslist.js, I click edit and the URL changes to /productdetails but I stay in the same productlist component, honestly routing in React is stupidly messy why won't they implemnt more straight forward routing....

Any help is apperciated

Comment: What is messy about it exactly? The React Router isn't part of React as standard, it's an additional package. It's a pretty elegant solution: You have a Router, you have Routes which have a path and a component to render when you're on that path?

Comment: Can you export your sample code to Stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry - didn't realise hitting enter would send a comment immediately. In order to debug this, can you try adding the `exact` prop and moving the `productDetails` Route to the top your of your switch to see if it is being caught by the other Routes, try removing all of the other Routes and see if you can get it to render from that? Also, is that your entire source code? Are you just using the switch + links?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use  in your code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import {Route, Switch, BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"; // <- you forgot to import <BrowserRouter>
import ProductsList from "./ProductsList";
import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

class Router extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <BrowserRouter> {/* You need to wrap your Routes in BrowserRouter */}
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                      <Route exact path="/products" component={ProductsList}/>
                      <Route path="/productdetails" component={ProductDetails}/>
                  </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Router;
```

Comment: I already added `BrowserRouter` in the main index.js `ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><Index/></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("app"));`